# Choose primary index for Global secondary index

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, throughput, capacity

I'm reading the AWS docs about secondary indices and I don't understand the following statement:

> The index key does not need to have any of the key attributes from the
>   table

From what I understand GSI allows me to create a primary or sort key on an attirubte in my table after its creation.

I would like to make sure I understand the statement above, does it mean exactly that I can create a primary or sort key on an attribute that is different from the current table's primary/hash key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is exactly what it means. Let's suppose that you have a table with a composite primary key that consists of `bundle_id` as the partition key and `item_id` as the sort key. Let's suppose you also have in that table an attribute called `client_id`.

You can then create a GSI, let's call it `client_id-index` with `client_id` as its partition key and you can include some other attributes in the GSI too.

Then you can query the GSI like this (code sample using Python and Boto3)

```
table.query(
    IndexName='client_id-index',
    KeyConditionExpression=Key('client_id').eq("123456")
)
```

Please note that even if you specify `ProjectionType` as `INCLUDE` in your GSI and your include some non-key attributes, the key attributes from the table will be also included in your GSI.

Comment: Great answer, very well explained. Thank you!

Comment: @SyndicatorBBB happy to help! :)